# How can I upload image from database and push it into <div> in php ?

Tags: php, database, database-connection

I have`<div>`in php like this..

[image]

I have Database name `"pv"` and table which have a lot of image name `"picture"`

How can load image from my table into `<div>` in php ?

My div code:

```
<div id = "leftContent">
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i<49; $i++)
    {
        echo"<div class = product>San Pham $i</div>";
        if($i%4==0)
            echo "<br />";
    }

?>
```

My css "product" code

```
{
width:180px;
height:190px;
float:left;
background-color:#33FF99    ;
border-right-color:#000000;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-width:1px;
border-style:dashed;
```

}

Please help I'm just newbie of PHP :(

Answer (score 0):

You did not give us much information about the DB you are using and the structure of it.
But as a starting point maybe you wanna read:

http://ch2.php.net/function.mysql-connect
or
http://www.cramerz.com/php/php_connect_to_db

If you have more concrete questions then, come back and ask.

hope this helps.